# Reshaping dataframes: partial stack or pivot using python. Columns into rows

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot, stack, reshape

I´m having several issues trying to re-shape a dataframe:

My current data looks similar to this:

```
YEAR    PROV P1_MALE P1_FEMALE P1_TOTAL P2_MALE P2_FEMALE P2_TOTAL  …
2019    A       1        3        4        5        1        6      …
2019    B       3        4        7        6        1        7      …
2019    C       2        1        3        1        1        2      …
2019    …       …        …        …        …        …        …      …
```

And I´m trying to get something like this:

```
YEAR    PROV    PERSON  MALE  FEMALE TOTAL
2019     A       P1      1      3      4
2019     A       P2      5      1      6
2019     B       P1      3      4      7
2019     B       P2      6      1      7
2019     C       P1      2      1      3
2019     C       P2      1      1      2
…        …        …      …      …      …
```

Thanks a lot for any guidance.